# Parallelizing a numba loop

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

Previously, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106434/parallelizing-a-maximum-over-an-nd-array-using-numba) about a relatively simple loop that Numba was failing to parallelize. A solution turned out to make all the loops explicit.

Now, I need to do a simpler version of the same task: I now have arrays `alpha` and `beta` respectively of shape `(m,n)` and `(b,m,n),` and I want to compute the computes the Frobenius product of 2D slices of the arguments and find the slice of beta which maximizes this product. Previously, there was an additional, large first dimension of `alpha` so it was over this dimension that I parallelized; now I want to parallelize over the first dimension of `beta` as the calculation becomes expensive when b>1000.

If I naively modify the code that worked for the previous problem, I obtain:

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def parallel_value_numba(alpha,beta):
    dot = np.zeros(beta.shape[0])
        for i in prange(beta.shape[0]):
            for j in prange(beta.shape[1]):
                for k in prange(beta.shape[2]):
                    dot[i] += alpha[j,k]*beta[i, j, k]
        index=np.argmax(dot)
        value=dot[index]
    return value,index
```

But Numba doesn't like this for some reason and complains:

```
numba.core.errors.LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
scalar type memoryview(float64, 2d, C) given for non scalar argument #3
```

So instead, I tried

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def parallel_value_numba_2(alpha,beta):
    product=np.multiply(alpha,beta)
    dot1=np.sum(product,axis=2)
    dot2=np.sum(dot1,axis=1)
    index=np.argmax(dot2)
    value=dot2[index]
    return value,index
```

This compiles as long as you broadcast `alpha` to `beta.shape` before passing it to the function, and in principal Numba is capable of parallelizing the numpy operations. But it runs *painfully* slowly, much slower than the serial, pure Python code

```
def einsum_value(alpha,beta):
    dot=np.einsum('kl,jkl->j',alpha,beta)
    index=np.argmax(dot)
    value=dot[index]
    return value,index
```

So, my current working code uses this last implementation, but this function is still bottlenecking the runtime and I'd like to speed it up. Can anyone convince Numba to parallelize this function with an appreciable speedup?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer with a solution, but formatting comments is harder.

Numba generates different code depending on the arguments passed to the function. For example, your code works with the following example:

```
>>> alpha = np.random.random((5, 4))
>>> beta = np.random.random((3, 5, 4))
>>> parallel_value_numba(alpha, beta)
(5.89447648574048, 0)
```

In order to diagnose the problem, it's necessary to have an example of the specific argument values causing the problem.

Reading the error message, it seems you are passing a `memoryview` object, but Numba may not have full [support](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/pysupported.html#bytes-bytearray-memoryview) for it.

As a side comment, you don't need to use `prange` in every loop. It's normally enough to use it in the outer loop, as long as the number of expected iterations is larger than the number of cores in your machine.